# Is there any way to hide deleted answers in "new answers to old questions" Tools section?

Tags: support, low-quality-posts, 10k-tools, late-answers

I have been looking through the [new answers to old question Tools section](https://askubuntu.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions) recently and have been flagging up quite a few things missed by others and the system. But what makes this extra annoying and long is the fact that some pages are entirely populated with deleted answers, and although it does show them to be deleted, when I am searching through those pages to try and find new things to flag up, having so many deleted answers is rather annoying.

So is there any way of viewing that section and having it hide deleted answers in the results?